# Jquery; why is this expression unrecognised when it should be already filtered out?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some JQuery code that is meant to work on nav links that are internal and beginning with a `#` .

However, the JQuery code instead states:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /files/tandcs.pdf
> jQuery 7
>  https://website.com/assets/js/main.js:78
> jQuery 2
>  https://website.com/assets/js/main.js:74

The code this relates to is here (the whole block):

```js
 // Scrollx function:
!function(t){function e(t,e,n){return"string"==typeof t&&("%"==t.slice(-1)?t=parseInt(t.substring(0,t.length-1))/100*e:"vh"==t.slice(-2)?t=parseInt(t.substring(0,t.length-2))/100*n:"px"==t.slice(-2)&&(t=parseInt(t.substring(0,t.length-2)))),t}var n=t(window),i=1,o={};n.on("scroll",function(){var e=n.scrollTop();t.map(o,function(t){window.clearTimeout(t.timeoutId),t.timeoutId=window.setTimeout(function(){t.handler(e)},t.options.delay)})}).on("load",function(){n.trigger("scroll")}),jQuery.fn.scrollex=function(l){var s=t(this);if(0==this.length)return s;if(this.length>1){for(var r=0;r<this.length;r++)t(this[r]).scrollex(l);return s}if(s.data("_scrollexId"))return s;var a,u,h,c,p;switch(a=i++,u=jQuery.extend({top:0,bottom:0,delay:0,mode:"default",enter:null,leave:null,initialize:null,terminate:null,scroll:null},l),u.mode){case"top":h=function(t,e,n,i,o){return t>=i&&o>=t};break;case"bottom":h=function(t,e,n,i,o){return n>=i&&o>=n};break;case"middle":h=function(t,e,n,i,o){return e>=i&&o>=e};break;case"top-only":h=function(t,e,n,i,o){return i>=t&&n>=i};break;case"bottom-only":h=function(t,e,n,i,o){return n>=o&&o>=t};break;default:case"default":h=function(t,e,n,i,o){return n>=i&&o>=t}}return c=function(t){var i,o,l,s,r,a,u=this.state,h=!1,c=this.$element.offset();i=n.height(),o=t+i/2,l=t+i,s=this.$element.outerHeight(),r=c.top+e(this.options.top,s,i),a=c.top+s-e(this.options.bottom,s,i),h=this.test(t,o,l,r,a),h!=u&&(this.state=h,h?this.options.enter&&this.options.enter.apply(this.element):this.options.leave&&this.options.leave.apply(this.element)),this.options.scroll&&this.options.scroll.apply(this.element,[(o-r)/(a-r)])},p={id:a,options:u,test:h,handler:c,state:null,element:this,$element:s,timeoutId:null},o[a]=p,s.data("_scrollexId",p.id),p.options.initialize&&p.options.initialize.apply(this),s},jQuery.fn.unscrollex=function(){var e=t(this);if(0==this.length)return e;if(this.length>1){for(var n=0;n<this.length;n++)t(this[n]).unscrollex();return e}var i,l;return(i=e.data("_scrollexId"))?(l=o[i],window.clearTimeout(l.timeoutId),delete o[i],e.removeData("_scrollexId"),l.options.terminate&&l.options.terminate.apply(this),e):e}}(jQuery);


//ScrollY function
(function(e){function u(s,o){var u,a,f;if((u=e(s))[t]==0)return n;a=u[i]()[r];switch(o.anchor){case"middle":f=a-(e(window).height()-u.outerHeight())/2;break;default:case r:f=Math.max(a,0)}return typeof o[i]=="function"?f-=o[i]():f-=o[i],f}var t="length",n=null,r="top",i="offset",s="click.scrolly",o=e(window);e.fn.scrolly=function(i){var o,a,f,l,c=e(this);if(this[t]==0)return c;if(this[t]>1){for(o=0;o<this[t];o++)e(this[o]).scrolly(i);return c}l=n,f=c.attr("href");if(f.charAt(0)!="#"||f[t]<2)return c;a=jQuery.extend({anchor:r,easing:"swing",offset:0,parent:e("body,html"),pollOnce:!1,speed:1e3},i),a.pollOnce&&(l=u(f,a)),c.off(s).on(s,function(e){var t=l!==n?l:u(f,a);t!==n&&(e.preventDefault(),a.parent.stop().animate({scrollTop:t},a.speed,a.easing))})}})(jQuery);
  


(function($) {

  var $main = $('#main');

  // Nav.
  var $nav = $('#nav');

  if ($nav.length > 0) {

    // Shrink effect.
    $main
      .scrollex({
        mode: 'top',
        enter: function() {
          $nav.addClass('alt');
        },
        leave: function() {
          $nav.removeClass('alt');
        },
      });

    // Links.
    var $nav_a = $nav.find('a');

    $nav_a
      .scrolly({
        speed: 1000,
        offset: function() {
          return $nav.height();
        }
      })
      .on('click', function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        // External link? Bail.
        if ($this.attr('href').charAt(0) != '#')
          return;

        // Deactivate all links.
        $nav_a
          .removeClass('active')
          .removeClass('active-locked');

        // Activate link *and* lock it (so Scrollex doesn't try to activate other links as we're scrolling to this one's section).
        $this
          .addClass('active')
          .addClass('active-locked');

      })
      .each(function() { // This is line 74

        var $this = $(this),
          id = $this.attr('href'),
          $section = $(id); // This is line 78
        // No section for this link? Bail.
        if ($section.length < 1 || Array.from($section)[0] !== '#')
          return;

        // Scrollex.
        $section.scrollex({
          mode: 'middle',
          initialize: function() {

            // Deactivate section.
            if (browser.canUse('transition'))
              $section.addClass('inactive');

          },
          enter: function() {

            // Activate section.
            $section.removeClass('inactive');

            // No locked links? Deactivate all links and activate this section's one.
            if ($nav_a.filter('.active-locked').length == 0) {
              $nav_a.removeClass('active');
              $this.addClass('active');

            }
            // Otherwise, if this section's link is the one that's locked, unlock it.
            else if ($this.hasClass('active-locked'))
              $this.removeClass('active-locked');

          }
        });

      });

  }


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#intro" class="active">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a href="#first">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href='#horses'>The Horses</a></li>
    <li><a href='#contactus' title='Finding Us'>Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href='/files/tandcs.pdf'>T&C's</a></li>
    <li><a href='/files/bookingform.pdf'>Booking Form</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Now, the function **WAS NOT WRITTEN BY ME** but as I understand it, it checks each anchor within the `<nav>` element and then if the anchor is not beginning with a `#` it aborts:

```
$nav_a.scrolly().on('click', function() {
    if ($this.attr('href').charAt(0) != '#')
        return;
    })
.each(function() { });
```

Which I thought would mean that the each element would only apply to the non-null values from the **on click** chained call.
Even so, I added my own qualifier inside the `.each` function to check the same thing

```
if ($section.length < 1 || Array.from($section)[0] !== '#')
        return;
```

But this appears after the issue flagged.

Basically, how do I go about making sure the onclick function doesn't screw up for non local links?

Comment: Please ensure your snippet *demonstrates* the problem.  It was missing jquery and is now missing `scrollex` - is `scrollex` relevant to your problem?  If it is, please include it, if it's not, please remove the code that attempts to call it, so that your snippet *demonstrates* the problem.  See [mcve].

Comment: `$section = $($this.attr('href'));` (which likely is the issue) occurs before you check if  $this.attr('href') starts with `#`

Comment: The code "it aborts" is inside the click handler, this has *no effect* on the subsequent `.each` handler  (this was hard to see until I reformatted your code) - you have `$nav_a.on("click", ()).each(...`

Comment: @freedomn-m I have added the missing SCrollX and ScrollY javascript; this is third party stuff

Comment: Probably easier to remove as I can now see that it's not relevant, but at least it now demonstrates the issue, thank you.

Comment: @freedomn-m ok so if the abort in the click handler has no effect, how can I make that abort have an effect on the original data ?

Comment: This line `if ($section.length < 1 || Array.from($section)[0] !== '#')` should be `if ($id.length < 1 || Array.from($id)[0] !== '#')` and placed directly above `$section = $(id)` (instead of after)

Comment: I have placed that in but now it states in browser "Uncaught ReferenceError: $id is not defined"

Comment: should I simply check if `$this` is empty/null immediately before here?

Comment: @freedomn-m Ok I solved the error by adding `$id === undefined` to the IF statements. If you'd like to put your help into an answer that can be ticked. Thank you `:-)`

Comment: @freedomn-m I think my core issue was that I thought the on click event would have already filtered the data before reaching the each; ie that the each worked on the data created through the on click preceding aspect.

Comment: That certainly didn't help.   The onclick callback (inside the `function()`) will only occur when the user clicks - you're setting up an event handler, not executing that code, while the `.each` is run immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the error stated as

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /files/tandcs.pdf

and you've already debugged to determine the error occurs on these lines:

```
      .each(function() { // This is line 74

        var $this = $(this),
          id = $this.attr('href'),
          $section = $(id); // This is line 78
        // No section for this link? Bail.
        if ($section.length < 1 || Array.from($section)[0] !== '#')
          return;
```

So `$(id)` is attempting `$("/files/tandcs.pdf")`, meaning `id` is `"/files/tandcs.pdf"` meaning `$this.attr("href")` is also that value.

You need to check if `id` is a valid value before attempting to use it.   Easiest is to check if it starts with "#" (as your attempt for $section):

```
.each(function() {
  
  let $this = $(this);
  let id = $this.attr("href") || "";
  if (!id.startsWith("#"))
      return;
```